# HTML canvas get angle from coordinates

Tags: javascript

I have a circle inside of a canvas (width: 200;height: 200) and a mouseove-event, that is supposed to get the angle of the hovered point to the center of my circle (x: 100; y: 100).
How can I get this angle?

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to find the difference between the mouse position (call it mouseX,mouseY) and the center of your circle, 100,100.

```
var dx = mouseX - 100;
var dy = mouseY - 100;
```

Then use a [bit of trigonometry](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan2.asp) to find the angle:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```